# "sql.h: No such file or directory" error trying to install pyodbc on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyodbc

Because I get the error :
" ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc' "

I installed pyodbc this way :

sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc

and

sudo pip install pyodbc

but on this last one I get following errors :

```
In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
  src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
   #include <sql.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyodbc
  Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ZuPGgc/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-XcninB-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-ajc2xi/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
    src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
     #include <sql.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ZuPGgc/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-XcninB-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZuPGgc/pyodbc/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have FreeTDS installed?

Comment: You are missing the ODBC headers. Try `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` and then re-try installing pyodbc via `pip`.

Comment: sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
worked, thx!